# How to temporary change div css for duration of executing another code?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have problem with temporary modifying div CSS for creating loading screen while something is computing or modifying area under shadow div.

**Expected result:**

0. Click button.
1. Div is masked with a shadow (for loading animation).
2. Code is doing something time hungry.
3. After 2 is done, shadow is removed.

**Current result**

0. Click button.
1. Code is doing something time hungry.
2. Div is masked with a shadow (Tested with commented PART 3).
3. Then is instantly removed, without being visible.

**Tried:**

This code with and without promise.

**Code snipped:**

```js
$('#butt').on('click', function() {
     console.log('test1');
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     //PART 1 ------------------------------------------------------
          let height = document.getElementById('el1').getBoundingClientRect().height
                  + document.getElementById('el2').getBoundingClientRect().height
                  + document.getElementById('el3').getBoundingClientRect().height;
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += height+'<br>';
          document.getElementById('shadow').style.height = ''+height+'px';
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += document.getElementById('shadow').style.height+'<br>';
          document.getElementById('shadow').style.top = ''+(-height)+'px';
          document.getElementById('shadow').classList.add("w3-show");
          document.getElementById('butt').classList.add("w3-disabled");
          resolve();
     }).then(() => {
     //PART 2 ------------------------------------------------------
          //Do anything that not finish instantly.
          let a = 0;
          let i = 10000;
          while(i!=0) {
            i--;
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += a;
            a = a + Math.log(a);
          };
          console.log('test2');
     }).then(() => {
     //PART 3 ------------------------------------------------------
          console.log('test3');
          document.getElementById('shadow').classList.remove("w3-show");
          document.getElementById('butt').classList.remove("w3-disabled");
     });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <button id='butt'>Show modal</button>
    <br>
    <p id='info'></p>
    <br>
    <div>
      <div id='el1' style="background-color: blue; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el2' style="background-color: green; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el3' style="background-color: red; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='shadow' class='w3-hide' style="position: relative; background-color: black; heigh:5px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.5; width:100px;">s</div>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The simplest way to temporarily apply CSS to a div is to add a class to it (that the temporary CSS targets) and then when you're done, remove that class.

Comment: Eak! jQuery code and css code in HTML !

Comment: Why do you want to use Promise in your case? I don't see a reason from it.

Comment: @jfriend00 In my final code let 'height = ...' is changeable, and I'm doing it for hide and disable css class here.

Comment: @Mister Jojo jQuery is from old code, atm im not adding more, css in html is just for prototype code here, not for the final code.

Comment: @ikhvjs It was experimental try, because without promise it still do not work as intended (All css changes are applied after all calculations instead of showing shadow then calculate then removing shadow).

Comment: @Maturutuki, I got you what you mean. I leave my answer to explain it.

Comment: Hint: That while loop is better described as "processor-hungry" rather than "time-hungry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a tricky question. Your first approach with synchrous code like below doesn't apply the css before the computation because DOM manipulation is `synchronous`, however, the browser's re-rendering of the page in response to a DOM update is `asynchronous`. That's why you don't see any updates of CSS because all the DOM manipulation applied immediately after all the `synchronous` is executed.

Example in `synchronous` below:

```js
$("#butt").on("click", function () {
    //PART 1 ------------------------------------------------------
    let height =
        document.getElementById("el1").getBoundingClientRect().height +
        document.getElementById("el2").getBoundingClientRect().height +
        document.getElementById("el3").getBoundingClientRect().height;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += height + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("shadow").style.height = "" + height + "px";
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML +=
        document.getElementById("shadow").style.height + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("shadow").style.top = "" + -height + "px";
    document.getElementById("shadow").classList.add("w3-show");
    document.getElementById("butt").classList.add("w3-disabled");
    console.log("test1");
    //PART 2 ------------------------------------------------------
    //Do anything that not finish instantly.
    let a = 0;
    let i = 10000;
    while (i != 0) {
        i--;
        a = Number(document.getElementById("info").innerHTML);
        a = a + Math.log(a);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = a;
    }
    console.log("test2");
    //PART 3 ------------------------------------------------------
    console.log("test3");
    document.getElementById("shadow").classList.remove("w3-show");
    document.getElementById("butt").classList.remove("w3-disabled");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <button id='butt'>Show modal</button>
    <br>
    <p id='info'></p>
    <br>
    <div>
      <div id='el1' style="background-color: blue; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el2' style="background-color: green; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el3' style="background-color: red; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='shadow' class='w3-hide' style="position: relative; background-color: black; heigh:5px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.5; width:100px;">s</div>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What you can do is to use async/await approach to wait for all the DOM manipulation is finished before.

Example below:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

$("#butt").on("click", async function () {
    //PART 1 ------------------------------------------------------
    let height =
        document.getElementById("el1").getBoundingClientRect().height +
        document.getElementById("el2").getBoundingClientRect().height +
        document.getElementById("el3").getBoundingClientRect().height;
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += height + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("shadow").style.height = "" + height + "px";
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML +=
        document.getElementById("shadow").style.height + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("shadow").style.top = "" + -height + "px";
    document.getElementById("shadow").classList.add("w3-show");
    document.getElementById("butt").classList.add("w3-disabled");
    console.log("test1");
    //PART 2 ------------------------------------------------------
    //Do anything that not finish instantly.

    await delay(100);

    let a = 0;
    let i = 10000;
    while (i != 0) {
        i--;
        a = Number(document.getElementById("info").innerHTML);
        a = a + Math.log(a);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = a;
    }
    console.log("test2");
    //PART 3 ------------------------------------------------------
    console.log("test3");
    document.getElementById("shadow").classList.remove("w3-show");
    document.getElementById("butt").classList.remove("w3-disabled");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <button id='butt'>Show modal</button>
    <br>
    <p id='info'></p>
    <br>
    <div>
      <div id='el1' style="background-color: blue; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el2' style="background-color: green; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='el3' style="background-color: red; heigh:10px; width:100px;">s</div>
      <div id='shadow' class='w3-hide' style="position: relative; background-color: black; heigh:5px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.5; width:100px;">s</div>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So an approach: Wait exactly amount of time needed to asynchronously re-render DOM is impossible and your suggestion is to guess that time, betting 100ms?

Comment: @Maturutuki, You may have a look of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: I tried something from this, but still same effect, DOM is rendered after everything is done. Looks like i need to stay with delay, thanks.

Comment: @Maturutuki, good that it helps. Anyway, would you accept this answer if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Your part 2 is not returning any promise so **.then()** will have no effect using on that block 3. You can return a new promise as such:

```
$('#butt').on('click', function() {
     console.log('test1');
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     //PART 1 ------------------------------------------------------
          let height = document.getElementById('el1').getBoundingClientRect().height
                  + document.getElementById('el2').getBoundingClientRect().height
                  + document.getElementById('el3').getBoundingClientRect().height;
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += height+'<br>';
          document.getElementById('shadow').style.height = ''+height+'px';
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += document.getElementById('shadow').style.height+'<br>';
          document.getElementById('shadow').style.top = ''+(-height)+'px';
          document.getElementById('shadow').classList.add("w3-show");
          document.getElementById('butt').classList.add("w3-disabled");
          resolve();
     }).then(() => {
     //PART 2 ------------------------------------------------------
          //Do anything that not finish instantly.
         return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          let a = 0;
          let i = 10000;
          while(i!=0) {
            i--;
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += a;
            a = a + Math.log(a);
          };
          console.log('test2');
          resolve()
          })

     }).then(() => {
     //PART 3 ------------------------------------------------------
          console.log('test3');
          document.getElementById('shadow').classList.remove("w3-show");
          document.getElementById('butt').classList.remove("w3-disabled");
     });
});
```

Comment: Does not change final effects, still all css is applied after after calculating while loop.